# Show that $(a, ∞)$ is an open set and that $(−∞, b]$ is a closed set for any $a$, $b$ in $\mathbf{R}$.

Tags: analysis

How to show that $(a, ∞)$ is an open set and that $(−∞, b]$ is a closed set for any $a$, $b$ in $\mathbf{R}$?

Comment: $(a,+\infty)$ is open because $(-\infty,a]$ is closed.

Answer (score 3):

Let us show that $(a,\infty)$ is open.

We need to find $\varepsilon >0$ so that $(x-\varepsilon, x + \varepsilon) \subseteq (a,\infty)$ for any $x \in (a,\infty)$, i.e. we need to find $\varepsilon$ such that any point in $(x-\varepsilon, x+ \varepsilon)$ is also in $(a,\infty)$.

Observe that it will suffice to show that $x-\varepsilon \geq a$ since
any number in $(x-\varepsilon, x + \varepsilon)$ must be strictly greater than $x-\varepsilon$.

Choose $\varepsilon = \dfrac{x-a}{2}$.

Then $x - \varepsilon = x - \dfrac{x-a}{2} = \dfrac{x + a}{2} \geq \dfrac{2a}{2}=a$

Now $(-\infty,b]$ is closed since its complement $(b,\infty)$ is open.

Comment: More simply, $\varepsilon=x-a$.